# Rewrite url writing using htaccess to access in a folder from root

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, magento, mod-rewrite

I want to write a rewrite url to one of my sub folder from root.
 Ex : **www.mydomain.com/subscriber.html**

want to redirect to

**www.mydomain.com/subscriber/index.php**

I used following code in my magento root .htaccess file.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.htm$ subscriber/$1.php [R,NC]
```

but it is not working.Any one can help me to short this issue?

Answer (score 0):

you can rewrite url from admin panel as below:
Catalog => URL rewrite management

Comment: thank you.It was a customized folder for subscribers.what is the id path in custom rewrite page in admin panel.

Comment: id path will be your page id ex.subscriber.html and request path will be subscriber/index.php.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
Redirect 301 /subscriber.html /subscriber/index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1/index.php [QSA,L]`

Comment: how the redirect engine verify that this is want to go to specific folder? if we write like this?

Comment: Is this you want? www.aaa.com/xxx.html -> www.aaa.com/xxx/index.php

Answer (score 0):

The following example could be helpful to use

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ $1/index.php [R,NC]
```

if you have specific a page `foo.html` and folder `foo` that you want to redirect to, then the following example might be helpful

```
RewriteRule ^foo\.html$ foo/index.php
```